# how to make nested where query using lambda expressions in c#

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I have Entity Customer that has collection of Campaigns, each campaign has collection of Stages. Each stage has nullable boolean property IsApprovedByAdmin.
So I need to make a query that will return me each stage that has property IsApprovedByAdmin is not assigned to true.
How to make that?

Example of not working query

```
DbContext.Set<Customer>().Find(customerId).Campaigns.Where(c => c.Stages.Where(s => s.IsApprovedByAdmin != true)).AsQueryable();
```

Comment: Currently you are trying to retrieve campaigns, but you say you want to retrieve stages? Can you clarify that? Do you need all campaigns that have a least one stage matching your criteria, or do you need the stages? I think if you manage to formulate your required query in plain english, the step to LINQ won't be too far :-)

Comment: I need stages. I didn't know how to write a query. Sorry for confusing

Comment: no worries. I was confused because you said you want nested "wheres" but you only have one "where" criterion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want `SelectMany`:

```
DbContext.Set<Customer>()
.Find(customerId)
.Campaigns.SelectMany(c => c.Stages)
.Where(s => !s.IsApprovedByAdmin);
```